# Writing nested loop as list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following for loop I need to make Pythonic by using a list comprehension:

```
accounts_list = []
for a in Accounts:
    rows = {
            'Account': a["FullyQualifiedName"],
            'Classification': a["Classification"],
            'AccountType': a['AccountType']
            }
    accounts_list.append(rows)
accounts_df = pd.DataFrame(accounts_list)
```

Comment: `[{ 'Account': a["FullyQualifiedName"], 'Classification': a["Classification"],'AccountType':a['AccountType'] } for a in Accounts]`

Comment: While @Epsi95's approach is correct, I wouldn't really call it pythonic, I believe keeping things as they are is cleaner than using list comprehension in this case. It just makes it hard to read and results in a line length > 80 characters

Comment: Yes, it loses readability

Comment: "I need to make Pythonic by using a list comprehension:" Pythonic != use list comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

```
accounts_list = [{'Account': a["FullyQualifiedName"],
                  'Classification': a["Classification"],
                  'AccountType': a['AccountType']} for a in Accounts]
accounts_df = pd.DataFrame(accounts_list)
```

Explanation:

1. This is a basic list comprehension:

```
[a for a in Accounts]
```

where the returned value of `[a for a in Accounts]` is the same as `Accounts`, if `rows` is of type `list`.

2. Add the dictionary for each iteration, and get

```
accounts_list = [{'Account': a["FullyQualifiedName"],
                  'Classification': a["Classification"],
                  'AccountType': a['AccountType']} for a in Accounts]
```

Comment: "rows" is a dictionary defined in the for loop though. I think that's where I'm getting stuck

Comment: @TomWoods Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could prepare a key mapping list and use it to build your target list items:

```
 keyMap = [ ['Account','FullyQualifiedName'],
            ['Classification']*2, ['AccountType']*2 ]

 accounts_list = [ {k:a[v] for k,v in keyMap} for a in Accounts ]
```